# Check a checkbox based on checkbox selection in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding

There is a checkbox that is already binded to boolean field "IsOutsourcing"

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkIsOutsourcing" IsChecked="{Binding IsOutsourcing, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

And I need to check it when checked another checkbox.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkIsOption1" IsChecked="{Binding IsOption1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

How ot can be done with XAML?

Can we use here multiple elements to bind?

```
IsChecked="{Binding IsOutsourcing chkIsOption1, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using MultiBinding with MultiValueConverter.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkIsOutsourcing">
    <CheckBox.IsChecked>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BooleanConverter}">
            <Binding Path="IsOutSourcing" />
            <Binding Path="IsChecked"
                        ElementName="chkIsOption1" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
</CheckBox>
```

The Converter,

```
public class BooleanConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool value1 = (bool)values[0];
        bool value2 = (bool)values[1];

        return value1 || value2;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```